# Postfix config doesn't change (even after a service restart)

Tags: email, postfix

I need to send emails with attachments. It used to work great, but the attachments are getting too big and I need to increase the message size.

I added `message_size_limit = 20480000` in /etc/postfix/main.cf and did `service postfix restart`.

But when I do `postconf -d | grep size` the message_size_limit is still at its previous value.

I don't really know what to do now.

Can you help in any way? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to get the actual value, you need to use the following command:

```
$ postconf | grep size
```

Adding `-d` option will show you the default values.

I quoted this from `man postconf`:

> -d     Print  main.cf default parameter settings instead of actual settings.  Specify -df to fold long lines for human readability
>   (Postfix
>                 2.9 and later).

Comment: That's the problem with copying lines from the Internet. Thank you!